# How do I get pygame to work on intel processor?

Tags: python, pygame

I downloaded Python 3.4 64 bit IDE and pygame but whenever I tried installing pygame it would say "Not supported on Intel".
So are there version of pygame available for Intel processor or are there any other ways to install pygame on an Intel processor?????

Comment: Try downloading pygame from [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads) the `pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_5974ff8dae3c+.win32-py3.4.msi` should be the one you need, because it supports python 3.4

Comment: Thanks Shiro, I have downloaded it and have it install but whenever I import the module in Python IDLE it tells me the module can not be found.

Comment: I am not using python IDE, so I can't say for sure what you are doing wrong. That version of pygame works for me.

Comment: What IDE are you using shiro?

Comment: Jetbrains Pycharm. It really doesn't matter. If you can't run pygame from the console, you are doing something wrong with the installation. I can't possibly know that... I am using the pygame version I linked you. If it doesn't work try previous versions of python/pygame, like 3.3

Comment: Thanks shiro for the concern you've shown. I got Jetbrains Pycharm, if intalled the pygame  I downloaded from the link you provided will it work?

Comment: As I said before, the IDE you are using doesn't matter at all. If you can run python from the command prompt, then your python/pygame setup is working fine.  This is what any IDE does behind the scenes when running python applications.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are running a 64bit version of Python. I tested this, and the version of Pygame you need runs on 32bit Python.

You can go to the Python download page for Python 3.4.3 fromhttps://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/
Make sure to download Windows x86 MSI installer.
[image]

Then you can download "pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_5974ff8dae3c+.win32-py3.4.msi" from https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads as Shiro as suggested.
[image]

After that you can install Python onto your system, and then pygame. Make sure that if you keep your 64bit version of Python, that you install Pygame to your 32bit version and run Pygame code on the 32bit IDE.

If you don't want to use IDLE, just make sure you have a 32bit version of Python.

Hopefully this helps. :)